# how to convert json object into class object

Tags: android

How to convert this json clsError and userId values:

```
String temp = "{"clsError":{"ErrorCode":110,"ErrorDescription":" Request Added"},"UserID":36}"
```

And pass them as parameters:

```
clsError errorObject=new clsError(UserID,clsError);
```

Comment: its json, not jason. that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use this: [http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)

```
JSONObject tempJson = new JSONObject(temp);
JSONObject clsErrorJson = tempJson.getJSONObject("clsError");
clsError errorObject = new clsError(tempJson.getString("UserID"),
                                    clsErrorJson.getInt("clsError") + ": "
                                    + clsErrorJson.getString("ErrorDescription"));
```

that is basically it. but i was not sure about the second parameter of the clsError constructor. i just assumed it is a string in my example :) but this should give you the idea how to do this. and you will have to surround that with try/catch. eclipse will tell you how :)

Comment: @Ankit Jain: thx for the edit. finally I know how I can make those links correct :) [linkurl][1] it is :) but no.. why can't i do it this way in posts? it won't accept that format :(

Answer (score 1):

I've found jackson's [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) to be extremely helpful in cases like this.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
clsError error = objectMapper.readValue(temp, clsError.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery extend method to wrap your json into javascript object as below:

```
function clsError(ErrorCode,ErrorDescription,UserID){
   this.ErrorCode=ErrorCode;
   this.ErrorDescription=ErrorDescription;
   this.UserID=UserID;
}

String temp="{"clsError":{"ErrorCode":110,"ErrorDescription":" Request Added"},"UserID":36}"
var obj = $.extend(new clsError(), temp);
```